# Convert string from text file inorder to plot using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, error-handling

I am trying to plot a graph using dates and integers from  a text file which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of text file]

However I keep getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Haeshan\Desktop\Comp Sci CC\graph.py", line 21, in 
>           graph()
>         File "C:\Users\Haeshan\Desktop\Comp Sci CC\graph.py", line 9, in graph
>           converters = {1: mdates.strpdate2num("%d/%m/%Y")})
>         File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 930, in loadtxt
>           items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>         File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 930, in 
>           items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>         File "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 659, in floatconv
>           return float(x)
>       ValueError: could not convert string to float: b"['10'"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def graph():
    date, value = np.loadtxt("Scores.txt", delimiter = ",", unpack=True,
                             converters = {1: mdates.strpdate2num("%d/%m/%Y")})
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg ="white")
    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value)
    plt.title("Performace")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    plt.xlabel("Date")
graph()
```

Any ideas,
Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496017/typeerror-when-using-matplotlibs-strpdate2num-with-python-3-2

Comment: because `date` is a string... if the first column said `10` instead of `['10']` it would be fine. `loadtxt` doesn't know to get rid of the brakets and quotes to parse the `'10'` to an int `10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your first column which has quotation marks. Since you have anyhow define converters I would change it to

```
converters = {0: (lambda x: int(x)),1: mdates.strpdate2num("%d/%m/%Y")})
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, due to the quotations marks I didn't see the other issues. TBH, I would not use `np.loadtxt` in this case since you have also the square brackets in each line. In addition you have the issue that you are using Python 3 where strings are unicode and not bytes anymore, but `loadtxt` is going for bytes (thus the  `b` in front of your line).
My suggestion is to read it in line by line and parse each line, e.g.

```
dates,values = list(),list()
formater = mdates.strpdate2num("%d/%m/%Y")
with open("Scores.txt",'r',newline='\n') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        # Remove the square brackets, quotation marks and newlines (if necessary)
        # Be aware that this will also kill all square brackets and quotations marks in your line
        entries = line.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace('\n','').split(',')
        values.append(int(entries[0]))
        dates.append(formater(entries[1]))
```

Comment: Sadly still gives an error but a different one                                    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b"['10'"

Comment: Hi   thanks for the update, I used your example but this popped up. "C:\Users\Haeshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: Also the formatting of the text file raises an error. when I append the list to the text file there is a space between the score (integer) and the date like shown in the image attached in the original post. however now it brings this up.                                                                        dates.append(formater(entries[1]))                                                    ValueError: time data ' 12/08/2016\r' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: Since you are working on Windows you have also to remove the '\r' as I did with the '\n'
... or instead of an additional `replace` you can do this directly in the formater by using '%d/%m/%Y\r' instead of '%d/%m/%Y' (but this is a rather unreadable hack TMO)

Comment: I added some more added the replace.  entries = line.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace('\r','').replace('\n','').split(',')  However the same error comes up. ValueError: time data ' 12/08/2016' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'   aren't they in the same format though?

Comment: No, somehow you have a space in front of the 12. So you need also to remove spaces to sanatise your input, but this is not a python specific problem, but an issue with the data.

Comment: You have at heading linespace so add `.strip()`  to the chain of modifications of the line variable before doing the conversion.