# fail to use numpy loadtxt to convert date with python3.6

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

My code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

stockFile = 'HistoricalQuotes.csv'

dates, close = np.loadtxt(stockFile, delimiter=',', unpack=True, usecols=(0,1), \
                          converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
print("Dates = ", dates)
```

and the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/zdlzdlxs/Documents/workspace/pynum_practice/part3/simplestats.py", line 7, in <module>
    converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
  File "/Users/zdlzdlxs/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1024, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/Users/zdlzdlxs/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1024, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/Users/zdlzdlxs/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 287, in __call__
    return date2num(datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(s, self.fmt)[:6]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 559, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 329, in _strptime
    raise TypeError(msg.format(index, type(arg)))
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

I've tried to find solutions in stackoverflow but failed.
Could anyone help me to convert datetime correctly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-date-stamps-matplotlib-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Thanks you two very much. The problem have been solved successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This date converter expects a regular string, which in Py3 is unicode.  But `loadtxt` loads the text as bytestrings:

```
In [12]: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')(b'1999-01-31')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

Modifying the converter to `decode` the bytestring should take care of the issue:

```
In [13]: fn = lambda astr: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')(astr.decode())

In [14]: fn(b'1999-01-01')
Out[14]: 729755.0
```

testing in loadtxt:

```
In [15]: txt=b"""1999-01-01
    ...: 2000-03-03
    ...: 2015-12-12
    ...: """

In [16]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:fn})
Out[16]: array([ 729755.,  730182.,  735944.])
```

Comment: @Jack If this answer fixed your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to it). This does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Hi, I have the very same problem but slightly different code and I cannot seem to get you solution to work. `date, bid, ask = np.loadtxt('data/GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack = True,
                               delimiter = ',',
                               converters = {0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}) `