# strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

date,open,close=np.loadtxt('000001.csv',delimiter=',',
                            converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')},
                            skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,4), unpack=True)

plt,plot(date,open)
```

But  `strptime()` argument 0 must be str, not

I have read all of about answers in the website, but these don't help me.

Comment: This is part of the awkward conversion from bytestrings to unicode in Py3.  `loadtxt` retains the Py2 bytestring operation.  Here's an example of previous SO questions dealing with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814724/fail-to-use-numpy-loadtxt-to-convert-date-with-python3-6

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905683/numpy-loadtxt-converters-error answer uses a `matplotlib.dates.bytespdate2num` class.  It's a superclass of the one you are using, but returns the bytestring that `loadtxt` likes.

Comment: And going back further in time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496017/typeerror-when-using-matplotlibs-strpdate2num-with-python-3-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decode the bytes `loadtxt`reads from the file.

Write a helper function:

```
def convert_date(date_bytes):
    return mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')(date_bytes.decode('ascii'))
```

and use it as converter:

```
date, open, close = np.loadtxt('000001.csv',delimiter=',',
                               converters={0: convert_date},
                               skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,4), unpack=True)
```

If `.decode('ascii')` doesn't work, try a different encoding.
Best would be to find out what the encoding of the file is.

Comment: I am appreciate your help. I am a  green hand for python, I have spend more than 4 hours for help from the internet, and helpless. You help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.