# According to tutorial fig did not need to be used, but receiving unused variable error in vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I got the following code from the sentdex Machine Learning for Forex tutorial

Whenever I run this code, an empty graph with no data plotted pops up.  The warning also shows that the variable fig is unused.

I've deleted the fig variable, tried importing pandas and running a version of the code using that syntax, and tried changing the backend used for matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np 

def graphRawFX():
 date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',', 
converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
 ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

 ax1.plot (date,bid)
 ax1.plot (date,ask)

 ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

plt.grid(True)
plt.show(True)
```

To display a graph that shows data plotted appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code stands right now, it basically, functionally, is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.grid(True)
plt.show(True)
```

It imports `plt` from `matplotlib`, then creates a grid and `show`s it. Nothing else in the code is being used.

All the work for plotting data would take place within `graphRawFX()` which is not ever being called.

The last two lines, `plt.grid(True)` and `plt.show(True)`, are improperly indented. They should be indented to lie within the function.

After that, you simply need to add `graphRawFX()` to the end of your code, without any indentation, to call the function and plot your data.

Here's a slightly cleaned up version of your code for better readability, and to ensure indentation is correct for all of the lines.

Note that `import matplotlib` and `import matplotlib.ticker as mticker` have been removed as well, as in this particular code, they're not necessary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


def graphRawFX():
    date, bid, ask = np.loadtxt(
                            'GBPUSD1d.txt',
                            unpack=True,
                            delimiter=',',
                            converters={
                                0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40, 40), (0, 0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date, bid)
    ax1.plot(date, ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show(True)

graphRawFX()
```

Note that the above code is only going to work in Python 2. To get it going in Python 3, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496215/214150

Comment: OMG Thanks!!  The workaround for Python 3 worked.  This has been frustrating me to no end since I am new to Python.

Comment: So glad I could help! And welcome to Python! You're gonna love it. A couple of suggestions: First, find an IDE you like (I personally love VS Code with the VS Code Python extension. It'll make such a big difference. Don't be intimidated by all it offers. Just use the bits you need. Second, don't be shy asking for help. Cheers!